# Opinion-based question receives factual answers (through comments)

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, opinion-based

I was wondering if there was a known reason for a specific .NET class to reside in a language-specific assembly: [Can TextFieldParser and other types from the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly be safely used in C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65006596/why-is-textfieldparser-class-part-of-microsoft-visualbasic-assembly)

It's been closed as "opinion-based", yet the **comments contain relevant facts that answered the question**.

To close a question like this one, whoever voted to close would have to:

1. *know* there's no good reason for the class to reside in that namespace (i.e. objective factual answer isn't *possible*), and
2. expect people to start guessing with merely subjective reasoning

Am I totally off base here?

Now the question has been closed as a duplicate, referring to a less distinct question with even less distinctive answers... :/

Comment: But do we know if the comments are factual, like... that's what the writer of the language actually said?

Comment: Fair point, @AndrewT.

Comment: @AndrewT. I guess a counter to that statement is that it's hard to show support in a comment - that information belongs in an answer. Still, hard to judge whether there is a specific reasoning used and announced by the authors by reading the question alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asking for the *Why* a design decision is made is always opinion based. It doesn't matter if the original members of the design team come along and answer that question or if the remarkable Hans Passant shares his valuable knowledge. In the end it is just an opinion.

What is interesting on your question isn't the *why* but the implications of that design decision.

That is kind of what you ask for in the body. I suggest you edit the title to read

> Can I use types from the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly like TextFieldParser in a C# program?

And then edit your body to make explicit you're interested in pitfalls when using that Type in your context. The why might get answered as a bonus.

I'm happy to re-open it after this edit so Hans can promote his comment to an answer so we properly document his knowledge.

Comment: "*Asking for the Why a design decision is made is always opinion based.*" [Related](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-doesnt-c-implement-top-level-methods)